# Is C# namespace compiled into IL files to be "complete" names?

Tags: c#, namespaces, il

E.g, if I have

```
namespace a
    namespace b
{
    class C...
    class D...
}
```

So after compiling, in IL file, where's the namespace information? Do I get two classes named a.b.C and a.b.D where the class names is prefixed by the namespace name?

Or I get a namespace a.b in the assembly file and having class C/class D inside it, just like C# code?

Comment: You could use something like ILDasm or ILSpy to have a look for yourself to see what it looks like.

Comment: C# doesn't get compiled to "IL files". It gets compiled to .NET DLLs, which you can then disassemble into IL files. Are you asking about the .NET DLLs, or the IL files you get from ildasm?

Comment: As suggested by niels, http://goo.gl/7xVmJU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other two responses wrote something, so I have to write the opposite :-)

Let's say that Microsoft kept the foot in both camps... Reading the [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf):

Page 114

> While some programming languages introduce the concept of a namespace, the only support in the CLI
>   for this concept is as a metadata encoding technique. Type names are always specified by their full
>   name relative to the assembly in which they are defined.

But then even this ECMA standard uses freely the namespace concept:

> In order to prevent name collisions into the future, all custom attributes in the System namespace are reserved for standardization.

And the IL language supports the `.namespace` instruction, that is equivalent to the namespace instruction of C# (this instruction is named in the ECMA standard but there are no examples. The ILASM compiles correctly this example and the decompiled code is what one would expect)...

```
.namespace A
{
    .namespace B
    {
        .class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
            extends [mscorlib]System.Object
        {
            // Nested Types
            .class nested public auto ansi beforefieldinit D
                extends [mscorlib]System.Object
            {
                // Methods
                .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
                    instance void .ctor () cil managed 
                {
                    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
                    // Code size 7 (0x7)
                    .maxstack 8

                    IL_0000: ldarg.0
                    IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
                    IL_0006: ret
                } // end of method D::.ctor

            } // end of class D


            // Methods
            .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
                instance void .ctor () cil managed 
            {
                // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
                // Code size 7 (0x7)
                .maxstack 8

                IL_0000: ldarg.0
                IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
                IL_0006: ret
            } // end of method C::.ctor

        } // end of class A.B.C
    }
}
```

But note that the generated code is equivalent to not using `.namespace` and including directly the full name in the `.class`:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit A.B.C
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Nested Types
    .class nested public auto ansi beforefieldinit D
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
        // Methods
        .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
            instance void .ctor () cil managed 
        {
            // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
            // Code size 7 (0x7)
            .maxstack 8

            IL_0000: ldarg.0
            IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
            IL_0006: ret
        } // end of method D::.ctor

    } // end of class D


    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

} // end of class A.B.C
```

And then the `Type` class has a `Name` and a `Namespace` properties. And the `Type` class (as a big piece of mscorlib) is integral to the good working of the CLR.

So if the question is: is there an explicit namespace in a compiled .NET program? The response is "no". There is only fullnames.

If the question is: is there the concept of namespace in .NET (at any/all levels)? The response is "yes". It is present both in IL (source code level, `.namespace`), CLR (.NET API, `Type.Namespace`), C# (the "main" language of .NET, used to write nearly all the .NET libraries) (`namespace`).

Comment: Well, that makes 2 people in our camp of "there are namespaces" :-) I believe the confusion is because the OP explicitly asked about IL. It's not about IL, it's about the metadata contained in the DLL with 'special' meaning, in this case: the dot notation meaning that it's a namespace. If you're asking about tokens, then a namespace doesn't have a metadata token -- but just because they don't have a metadata token ID by themselves, doesn't mean that they don't exist. To be fair, you cannot have a namespace without a type though.

Answer (score 5):

The CLR doesn’t know anything about namespaces. When you access a type, the CLR
needs to know the full name of the type and
which assembly contains the definition of the type so that the runtime can load the proper assembly,
find the type, and manipulate it.

It mean that your `class C` in `namespace b` is stored like `b.C`.

Comment: `The CLR doesn’t know anything about namespaces.` mmmh... The CLR without any assembly doesn't know anything about namespaces true... But `mscorlib` is integral to CLR, and `mscorlib` contains the `Type` object, that do knows of namespaces.

Comment: Yes, of course, you are right, but CLR doesn't using this information for finding type and manipulating it.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces do not exist in IL. They are not preserved as metadata. In IL, all references to types and methods must be made using fully-qualified names.

IL, however, recognises and explicitly allows that a type name contain dots. C# or VB.NET namespaces are a language construct built on top of that: They are essentially a mechanism that allows you to only specify the latter dot-separated parts of a type name. `using` or namespace `Imports` directives are hints to the compilers for guessing the former parts of incomplete type names; but in all cases, the compiler has to translate non-fully-qualified names (`SomeType`) to fully-qualified type names (`SomeNamespace.SomeType`).

Comment: I would say it is a little more nuanced... At the IL level perhaps there are no namespaces, but at the .NET level (CLR/API) they surely are present/known/recognized (the `Type` "object" fully supports them for example).

Comment: @xanatos: Thanks for hinting at `Type`, I didn't think about that. So namespaces as a concept are not just present in the higher-level languages, but also in the framework class library (API design). (Nevertheless the fact remains: namespaces do not exist at the metadata / IL level.)

Comment: @stacx Technically at the IL level there is a `.namespace` instruction. It is optional (you can include the name directly in the `.class`). See my response. As everything about IL code it is badly documented :-)

Comment: @stakx Just because they don't have a metadata token, doesn't mean they don't exist. The fact that a `Type` always knows the namespace property proves the exact opposite. If you want to be exact, the only thing you can say is that you can't reference a namespace metadata token in IL.

Comment: @xanatos: Read again what I wrote. I didn't say, "namespaces don't exist". I said, "namespaces don't exist *at the metadata / IL level*". But yes, they do exist in the higher-level languages and API.

Comment: @stakx As I've written, it is very nuanced... You can say they don't exist at the IL "source code" level, and see the `.namespace` instruction as a shortcut, and it would be right, or you can say that they do exist, but they can be implicitly subsumed in the full name that you can use in the `.class` instruction. Both interpretations are right. As I've written in my response, *Microsoft kept the foot in both camps*

Answer (score 1):

Let's get something straight first.

- IL is basically just the 'basic building block' language used in .NET
- A DLL contains IL and metadata

You can see both if you fire up `ildasm` (from a visual studio command prompt), put your DLL in there, dump everything and then browse it in your favorite text editor. That'll contain both the metadata and the IL code.

IL doesn't contain namespace info, it's just composed of 'tokens', which are basically ID's to classes, functions, etc. These ID's can be resolved.

One of the things in a DLL is the metadata container for a namespace. Or as ILDASM will show you:

```
// ================================= M E T A I N F O ================================

// ===========================================================
// ScopeName : MyNamespace
// MVID      : {22EE923F-126A-43BA-8A72-59A7A069625A}
// ===========================================================
// Global functions
// -------------------------------------------------------
// 
// Global fields
// -------------------------------------------------------
// 
// Global MemberRefs
// -------------------------------------------------------
// 
// TypeDef #1 (02000002)
// -------------------------------------------------------
//  TypDefName: MyNamespace.MyType  (02000002)
//  Flags     : [Public] [AutoLayout] [Class] [AnsiClass]  (00000001)
//  Extends   : 01000001 [TypeRef] System.Object
//  Field #1 (04000001)
```

Now, what you basically call a namespace is the collection of typedefs metadata tokens that start with the same 'dot' prefix. A namespace isn't really an 'entity', which means it has no token by itself. A namespace only exists because there are names of the types that include dots (which do have tokens). In other words, a namespace doesn't exist directly; it's derived from the types that are there.

Now, knowing this, your question can easily be answered:

> So after compiling, in IL file, where's the namespace information? Do
>   I get two classes named a.b.C and a.b.D where the class names is
>   prefixed by the namespace name?

Yes, and without them, the namespace wouldn't exist.