# Change namespace on dynamic loading of assembly

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have an app which uses a specific type in a separated dll (developed by someone else).
Say it is InnerType :

```
namespace SeparatedAssembly
{
   public class InnerType 
   {

   }
}
```

Until now, I was referencing a version of this dll in Visual Studio and I was using the InnerType in my app. However, since the code inside the InnerType could change, the assembly is loaded at runtime with the "AssemblyResolve" event.

But now, the namespace of this class has changed :

```
namespace SeparatedAssembly.Inner
{
   public class InnerType
   {

   }
}
```

So, I have an exception TypeLoadException because my app can't find this type anymore. I can't just reference this new version and change the namespace I use, because it as to be compatible with the old versions of this dll.

So my question is: is it even possible to specify the namespace to look for in an assembly, in the AssemblyResolve event?
If there is a way to catch this exception and try with a different namespace, it's also OK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the full name of the method to be called is specified in the calling assembly, and you can't "rewrite" it in an easy way. The namespace is part of the name. I'll make a reference to another response I gave some time ago: [Is C# namespace compiled into IL files to be “complete” names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797415/is-c-sharp-namespace-compiled-into-il-files-to-be-complete-names).

To give an example in [TryRoslyn](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:>il/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUHiAQ3VRAAdCBjVGAMQHt68BvPGdmM4AIwBsxKMSr0IgQMAEKEATjFa4Oizj36CAbvTAATGAC1GACgCUctkvMBhehBD1eqAHQB1aWDQAZSKgMAiABKovLz0PkY4CuYwAL5m7DG4UUA==):

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar 
    {
        public void Zoo() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

is translated to

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Foo.Bar
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
```

(the namespace `Foo` is directly part of the name `Foo.Bar`)

and then the method call to `Console.WriteLine` is:

```
call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

Comment: Even if the answer is negative, it's helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonyjack I've given a little thought on your problem, and I can't see an easy solution, or even a not-so-easy solution. You could create some shim classes (one for the old .dll and one for the new .dll) and derive both of these shim classes from a common interface (and then use only this common interface in your code), but depending on what you do with the objects of the dll it could be very difficult.